# Checking situations in a period or terminate when timeout

Tags: java, concurrency

I want to implement a functionality, which should look like this:

```
WaitingUtility.repeatASupplier(getTheNeededSupplier()).every(100).for(10).now();
```

The Supplier should be/can look like a Supplier in guava: http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Suppliers.html
If the suppliers says false, then the utility keeps on asking and waiting, 
if "true" the utility stops waiting.

With the every(100) i mean every 100 milliseconds, the supplier is asked for the result.
With for(10): If the 10 seconds are over the Utility-Class stops.

I can think of several implementations and solutions: Timer, ExecutorService, "own" Threadhandling...

Is there an existing solution?
What's the best solution for it?

Thanx

Comment: Maybe you should have a look at Java's `ExecutorService`s and especially its use of [Future](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html). This may give you some ideas to get you started in the right direction.

Comment: I was thinking about it. However, I'm not shure, if there is a better solution by using an already existing framework/abstraction.

Comment: When using a scheme as that of those `Future`s, the solution would/should not have to poll the supplier but will implicitly use the proper synchronization mechanisms, such as `wait()` and `notify()`.